# Single auth URL? Why not authenticate on ANY URL?

Tags: authentication, architecture, web-applications, model-view-controller

Why hello SOers. My question today is about authentication endpoints and the architecture surrounding them.

Most web frameworks and applications I've encountered seem to have a single URL or endpoint to deal with 'authentication' - e.g. processing authentication tokens such as usernames and passwords, and doing something with them.

It seems to me like this causes a lot of follow-on work, like for example if you hit an auth-required URL, the system needs to pass that URL to the authentication endpoint in order to redirect you back there after authentication and authorisation.

Why not simply listen for authentication tokens on EVERY URL endpoint? With a modern MVC framework utilising a PageController or FrontController pattern this should be simple.

Am I missing the downsides of such an approach? Do some frameworks already utilise such a system? Opine me!

Comment: That's what most frameworks do already. Every request received is has it's authentication cookie checked before page processing begins

Comment: #TFD - My point exactly; post that as an answer and I'll vote it up :)

Comment: @TFD: i'm not sure you understood the question. many frameworks have one endpoint for authentication through username and password, that creates a session stored in what you call the "authentication cookie". the mechanism you describe has less to do with authentication, then with sessions actually.

Comment: back2dos is on the money. I'm not talking about session authentication, but initial authentication (does it have a name?)

Answer (score 1):

> > Why not simply listen for authentication tokens on EVERY URL endpoint?

Ignoring the word end-pont for a moment, that's what the out-of-the-box Microsoft Forms based authentication does; in the config you specify the parts of the site you want to protect (like the "admin" folder, whatever), you can have as many of these as you like.

When the user hits anything covered by that (as long as IIS pipes it to the ASP.NET processor) they will need to be authenticated (if they aren't already).

I would imagine the ASP.NET MVC works in exactly the same way.

Not sure if that answers your question (?)

Comment: If I remember correctly, ASP.net uses a RETURN_URL parameter off a Login.aspx page on authentication. My point is why can I simply not POST my credentials to ANY .aspx page and have it authenticate me without redirection?

Comment: Well I guess you could, but why would you want to?  The FormsAuth module does this for you, so where's the extra work?  

Building authentication into everypage - that would add extra work, if not then certainly extra complexity; and all you'd be saving is one redirection, right?

If you think you can do it using a controller (in MVC) then give it a shot - no harm in trying :)